# Keycloak 18.0 with Postgres 10.21

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to run  Keycloak 18 with postgres 10.21

Here is my docker compose

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  keycloaksvc:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0
    user: '1000:1000'
    container_name: "testkc"
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_ADDR=postgressvc
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_SCHEMA=public
      - DB_USER=KcUser
      - DB_PASSWORD=KcPass
      - KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - REDIRECT_SOCKET=proxy-https
      - KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=testing

    volumes:
       - ./ssldir:/etc/x509/https
       - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
       - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
       - "/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro"
       - ./kcthemes:/opt/keycloak/themes

    entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --auto-build  --hostname-strict-https=false  --http-relative-path=/auth --features=token-exchange  --https-certificate-file=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt --https-certificate-key-file=/etc/x509/https/tls.key
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      - postgressvc



  postgressvc:
    image: postgres:10.21-alpine
    user: '1000:1000'
    container_name: "kc_postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_USER=KcUser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=KcPass
    volumes:
      - ./pgdta:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro"
    network_mode: "host"
```

It runs  fine and  I can get to admin console  https://localhost:8443/auth/admin

I can also add  new realm and users.  However I do not see any data in  postgres.  If I make change in docker-compose file and restart,  all the realms and users are lost

Exact same  postgres setup works fine with  image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1

What setup  am I missing for keycloak 18 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keycloak from [version 17](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/02/keycloak-1700-released) has major changes (it is based on the Quarkus) and also config has been changed. So don't use config, which is working with Keycoak 16, but check the current Keycloak doc, e.g. https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers

You will find that DB env variables are now:

```
KC_DB_URL,KC_DB_USERNAME,KC_DB_PASSWORD,...
```

Also other env variables have been changed, so it is not only about DB env variables.

Comment: How can we specify postgressvc  in the Keycloak section ?  What is the equivalent of DB_ADDR ?  Has it been replaced by KC_DB_URL ?

Comment: KC_DB_URL works

Comment: I'd be really thrilled to know where to find the exhaustive list of all those new variables !

Comment: @tisc0 https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config just transform it to the env variable name convention, e.g. `db-url` => `KC_DB_URL`.

Comment: Yeah, just find it ! I didn't clic on the little arrows to unfold explanations for each variable ! Thanks @JanGaraj

Answer (score 5):

I am also facing the same issue with keycloak v19.0.0 . It was storing data in memory.
But with below configuration able to store data in postgres.

```
keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: user
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_EDGE: proxy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.0
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command:
      - start-dev --auto-build
```